# Need a simple Linux C++ IDE (Android NDK)

Tags: linux, gcc, ide, android-ndk

I need an IDE that must:

1. allow running the ~/android-ndk-r7/ndk-build script for
   compilation;
2. intercept the gcc output and show it to me;
3. when I click on an error line, go to error location: open the mentioned file at the mentioned line.

I have a large existing C++ project and am porting it to Android/NDK.

(Neither Code::Blocks nor Eclipse do the 3rd. Maybe I am missing something?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I configured Code::Blocks for Android NDK/JNI development, but there's a trick.
Codeblocks believes that it can know what compiler you use, and wants to stop you from using something it does not know. You have to trick it.

1. Create an empty codeblocks project
2. Add your source and header files (manually)
3. Click the right mouse button on your project in the workspace (the left pane). You will see a menu: [image: the two useful menu items] 
   (EDIT: First go to *Properties* and specify it's a custom Makefile, then to *Build options*)
4. Go to "Properties" and tell CB it has a custom Makefile. Do not tell it anything close to the truth about the platform: it will tell you that you don't have the required compiler and will not even attempt to build something.
   [image: custom makefile]
5. Finally, in the *Build options*, select the GNU GCC Compiler, go to the "Make commands", and write your custom commands. (Personally I created a Makefile that invokes ndk-build -- I prefer to keep scripts in the text files rather than in GUI dialogs. The item that you might want to change is `-j 4`)[image: build options]

And one final note: if your configuration does not work, you get no meaningful diagnostics.

PS Here's my Makefile:

```
all:
    @echo '====all===='
    pwd;~/android-ndk-r7/ndk-build -j 4
clean:
    @echo '====clean===='
    pwd;~/android-ndk-r7/ndk-build clean

.PHONY: clean
.PHONY: all
```

Comment: Options in step 4 are disabled. Step 5 should be done before step 4 so the make options will be editable.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work; it seams whatever i put into step 4 is ignored, and errors with "No rule to make target 'Debug'".

Comment: After playing around with it; I managed to get it to work. And this is awesome!! I forgot to change "silent build" to `bash -c ". ~/.bashrc; make"` and everything to related.

Comment: Could you post source of working example to an opensource repository? (e.g. github) Thanks.

Comment: The source of my employer's software? No, I could not.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ARM Development Studio 5 (DS-5)](http://ds.arm.com/). The Community Edition is free for non-commercial use and offers integration with the NDK in Eclipse.

Further, I believe if you dig around a bit you'll find non-official instructions from various sources on how to integrate the NDK in Elipse. For example, look at some of this:

- [Using Eclipse for Android C/C++ Development](http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/)
- [Using Eclipse for Android C/C++ Debugging](http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-debugging/)

Comment: Thank you for the Eclipse links; it worked, but Eclipse is no coding sunshine: it detects "errors" (like the logging function not found) that are no problem for the compiler and linker, and you have to *manually delete* error messages to run your code.

Comment: Which logging error are you referring to? As for sticky errors, yes this is how Eclipse is designed. Still, it's the environment Google suggests and provides plugins/etc. for (non-NDK) and about the best there is right now.

Comment: It's no logging error; I defined the invocation of Android logging as LOGD and DLOG macros (two names are easier than remembering which one), and each time I open a C source file Eclipse is telling me that there is no such function (I do not remember the exact name, it's long), but the code compiles and runs and the function _is_ invoked because it works. So it's a false positive.

Comment: Here's a link about that false positive and fighting the darkness (the Eclipse): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258451/false-error-from-eclipse-function-android-log-print-could-not-be-resolved/

Answer (score 0):

Emacs is what you're looking for. To compile in emacs, simply open a source file, then select 'Tools->Compile'. You can change the default compile command from "gmake -k" to whatever you want. In your case, the specific build script. After it is done compiling, you can click on errors and it will open the appropriate source file and line.

Emacs is a complete IDE and there are many plugins to add capabilities. Best of which EDE (Emacs Dev Env). Not sure which distribution you're using, but Emacs is certainly a standard package in all of them.

Comment: Err... Emacs is... well... a bit esoteric. Is there a more intuitive option?

Comment: Maybe, but so is 2^64-1. I've use kdevelop in the past. It will do what you want. But I prefer emacs. If you want really esoteric, try vim, which can also meet your requirements.

Comment: The funniest thing about Emacs is that from the command line `~/android-ndk-r7/ndk-build clean all` fails on a syntactic error, but from Emacs it fails on the linking phase. I had to `cd /full/path/to/myProject/jni/` to fix it.

Comment: Well, I did that using Xemacs. It is easy to configure keys to perform custom functions, but the UI is awful, starting from missing icon images on buttons and ending with impossibility to paste text into the search dialog. Under Linux it looks like a Windows port of a Linux program. But it did let me do the most important repeated operations quickly.