# false error from Eclipse: Function '__android_log_print' could not be resolved (Android, CDT)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, eclipse-cdt

I have an Android NDK project whose NDK part compiles ok from command line;
I used to have no problems with running the compiled stuff from under Eclipse as a pure Java project. But I converted it to a C/C++ project and now cannot even run it.

I see in the "Console" that the library is built,
BUT: Eclipse tells me that my project has errors and it will not run it.
(Why on Earth? The code *is* compiled!!!)

I have resolved some issues with missing symbols by adding include paths to the project properties.

But I'm still getting this weird 
`Function '__android_log_print' could not be resolved`
error.

So, two questions:

1. **How do I get rid of this error?** (Can it be ignored?)
2. **Plan B: how do I convert this mixed C/C++/Java project to a pure Java one?**

= = =

PS "As you call the ship, so it will do". Could not they just find a better name for an IDE, something like "Lucid coding"? (Rhetoric question)

= = =

UPDATE: It looks like Eclipse reports errors only for the files that it sees (that is, shows you). I have opened another file with a LOGD macro, and the Eclipse reported an error for it too. I have closed all file windows, closed Eclipse *and* deleted a .something file. After that, I was able to run the application. I did not risk to open the source files with that logging macro. (That's very far from "Lucid coding", isn't it?)

Comment: See also: how to use Code::Blocks instead of Eclipse:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079592/need-a-simple-linux-c-ide-android-ndk/9668394#9668394

Answer (score 6):

The configuration of CDT indexer needs to enable "Index unused headers ..."

How to get there: Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Indexer.

[image]

Gets rid of the error for me.

Answer (score 2):

How it can be ignored: open 'Problems' window, select errors in c/c++ files and press Del key. A confirmation msg box will be shown, but after that you can debug your app... until next rebuild =)
Alternatively, as you mentioned earlier, you can just close all opened c/c++ files.

Comment: I... errr... have closed it. It did not help then, but now I don't know how to open the "Problems" window again.

Answer (score 1):

In your Android.mk file, please add

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid
```

The `__android_log_print` isn't part of libc, it's in the log library, so you need to explicitly declare it to be linked in.

Note the eclipse will refuse to run the project if there's errors on either the C or java side. In this case, there's a linker error; the code didn't successfully finish compiling, so it won't run it.

Comment: I _do_ have ``-llog`` in ``Android.mk``, otherwise there would be a link error in the command line. Just in case I added liblog.so to the list at the "Libraries" tab and added the ..arch-arm/usr/lib to the "Library Paths" tab. I'm still getting the same error. Eclipse does not want to run the project whose compilation completed successfully.

Comment: I repeat: there is _no link error_. I _was_ able to run the project before converting it to a mixed C/Java one.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can retype these strings and restart an Eclipse; All these fixes sounds lame though...