# Eclipse does not seem to recognize Native Android code

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk, native-code

I am trying to learn about native Android, using NDK.

I find some sample projects in NDK folder and on the Internet. After much configuration, they are runnable.

But, my problem is: when I open a `.c` or `.h` file in JNI folder with Eclipse (just want to see what it is), Eclipse shows many error in this file. For example, it don't know what is `JNIEnv`, `jobject`, `jstring`.

I haven't made any change in the project, just opening it. Errors mean I can't rerun it again except if I delete it from the workspace then reimport it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse does not work well with C/C++ files. At least, for me it did not.
After some search, I have managed to configure Code::Blocks to support NDK, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9668394/755804) to the question:
[Need a simple Linux C++ IDE (Android NDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079592/need-a-simple-linux-c-ide-android-ndk) .

Comment: I just find that error only on Windows, Ubuntu is not. I haven't thought about using any other IDE. I will try this. Thanks you